# Helm - Error: x509: cannot validate certificate for 127.0.0.1 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs

Tags: ssl, kubernetes-helm, helm-tls

I am getting below error when I install `helm` with TLS. I applied the given solution here: https://helm.sh/docs/tiller_ssl/#troubleshooting but, still it's not working.

> Error: x509: cannot validate certificate for 127.0.0.1 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs

**generating SSL files:**

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -keyout helm.ca.key.pem -out helm.ca.cert.pem -subj "/C=CA/ST=St/L=Ms/O=Fi/OU=Dp/CN=tiller" -days 7200 -extensions v3_ca -nodes
openssl genrsa -out ./helm.tiller.key.pem 4096
openssl genrsa -out ./helm.client.key.pem 4096
openssl req -key helm.tiller.key.pem -new -sha256 -out helm.tiller.csr.pem -subj "/C=CA/ST=St/L=Ms/O=Fi/OU=Dp/CN=tiller-server"
openssl req -key helm.client.key.pem -new -sha256 -out helm.client.csr.pem -subj "/C=CA/ST=St/L=Ms/O=Fi/OU=Dp/CN=helm"

echo subjectAltName=IP:127.0.0.1 > extfile.cnf
openssl x509 -req -CA helm.ca.cert.pem -CAkey helm.ca.key.pem -CAcreateserial -in helm.tiller.csr.pem -out helm.tiller.cert.pem -days 1800 -extfile extfile.cnf
openssl x509 -req -CA helm.ca.cert.pem -CAkey helm.ca.key.pem -CAcreateserial -in helm.client.csr.pem -out helm.client.cert.pem  -days 1800 -extfile extfile.cnf
```

**helm init:**

```
helm init --tiller-tls --tiller-tls-cert ./helm.tiller.cert.pem --tiller-tls-key ./helm.tiller.key.pem --tiller-tls-verify --tls-ca-cert helm.ca.cert.pem
kubectl -n kube-system wait --for=condition=Ready pod -l name=tiller --timeout=300s
helm ls --tls --tls-ca-cert ./helm.ca.cert.pem --tls-cert ./helm.client.cert.pem --tls-key ./helm.client.key.pem
```

Comment: Based on the error message you need to create a certificate with a SAN section having an `IPAddress` member. With recent enough versions of `openssl`, you can use `-addext` for that. See this as an example: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/183973 but use IPAddress instead of DNS.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I think, that's what I am doing with this flag: `-extfile extfile.cnf`

Comment: Unfortunately the file has to be formatted differently, see various extensions online (as you do it the command can not know it is a SubjectAlternativeName extension). You also probably call it too late, you need to do it at the CSR step, it is an integral part of that the CA has to sign.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek So, I removed `extfile` and using `openssl req -key helm.tiller.key.pem -new -sha256 -out helm.tiller.csr.pem -subj "/C=CA/ST=St/L=Ms/O=Fi/OU=Dp/CN=tiller-server" -addext "subjectAltName = IP:127.0.0.1"` But, still getting the same error.

Comment: Your command works on my side, the CSR has `Requested Extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                IP Address:127.0.0.1`. Make sure the final certificate has that data too, and make sure you restart your systems with the new certificate.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek From where did you get that info? According to this guide https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSB23S_1.1.0.13/gtps7/cfgcert.html it's not like the way you mentioned. And I am getting an error: `139754355836672:error:22075075:X509 V3 routines:v2i_GENERAL_NAME_ex:unsupported option:crypto/x509v3/v3_alt.c:531:name=IP Address`

Comment: From where I got the info? I tried the command myself and looked at the results!

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I have a similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67558966/self-signed-ca-cannot-validate-certificate-for-192-168-178-66-because-it-doesn?noredirect=1&lq=1
In the end, my CSR file indeed contains the `Subject Alternative Name: IP Adress`-part. But my CRT-File doesn't!